# How to estimate an mlogit (R package) model with a fixed (offset) variable

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, logit, offset

I am trying to estimate a multinomial logit model using an offset variable with the mlogit package of R

Using the syntax here [https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html] it seems that the correct way to do this is to use something like this

```
v <- mFormula(choice ~ gc + log_gc + offset(log_attr) + 0)
```

which you would then pass to the model estimation as

```
model <- mlogit(v, mlogit_data)
```

Printing the coefficients seems to indicate that the parameter has not been estimated

```
model$coefficients
          gc       log_gc 
-0.003023088 -0.477115780 
attr(,"fixed")
    gc log_gc
```

However these parameters are exactly the same as the parameters I get if I don't include the variable log_attr at all... ie

```
v_no_log_attr <- mFormula(choice ~ gc + log_gc + 0)
model_no_log_attr <- mlogit(v_no_log_attr, mlogit_data)
model_no_log_attr$coefficients
          gc       log_gc 
-0.003023088 -0.477115780 
attr(,"fixed")
    gc log_gc 
 FALSE  FALSE
```

Given that the data has significant variation in this variable, I feel that this is unexpected and that the mlogit package is simply ignoring the offset variable.

[image: variation_in_data]

Is this possible to do with this package? Do I have a misunderstanding of how to perform the estimation?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I think mlogit does not allow offset as you can see here : https://github.com/cran/mlogit/blob/master/R/mlogit.R so it ignores the offset variable.

Comment: Now `mlogit`  uses the `Formula` package, which now seems to allow for offsets, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Formula/vignettes/Formula.pdf